# php_mssql.dll file not in Wamp2.2d

Tags: sql-server-2008, wampserver

I have installed Wamp 2.2d, having php 5.3.10.
I have read some where that Wamp doesnot comes with" php_mssql.dll" the dll file used to connect MS Sql Server with php.. 
When i try to load the php_mssql.dll extension error comes that unable to load module, it donot exist. 
Please any body tell me where to download that .dll file and how to connect with MS SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get MSSQL working on PHP is to go to [this Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx) and follow the [`Beginner's Guide`](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx). It goes through all the information you need to get the PHP MSSQL client running.

Comment: Thats a great tutorial, but my prob is different., The drivers which they give doenot include php_sqlsrv.dll, The apache error log file says that it cannot load the module, when i try to load this extension from the menu tray php/extentions..

Comment: @HanyaIdrees What version of WampServer are you running? 32-bit or 64-bit version?

Comment: 64 bit, Wamp 2.2d, php 5.3.10,

Comment: @HanyaIdrees Sorry, x64 is your problem then, MSQL drivers for PHP currently don't support x64 :-(

Comment: hmmmm, r u sure. means i have to work with My SQL databasr then

Comment: @HanyaIdrees All DLLs in the driver package from Microsoft are 32-bit DLLs `PE32 executable for MS Windows (DLL) (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit` and will not work for x64. There may be a possibility to compile your own from sources, but I'd hesitate to do that for a production system. Any particular reason for you not to run 32-bit?

Comment: I have one 64 bit pc, is that dll's u are talking about work on my 64 bit, i will definitely very happy to use them,. Otherwise i have no option

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my problem. Now i can think of other options. Thanks